# Send data to url in form handler

Tags: php, forms, salesforce, recaptcha

I have a salesforce form, that sends form data to salesforce_url.  I am implementing a form handler.  How do I send data to salesforce-url in the form handler.  In the basic form it would be sent via

```
<form action="salesforce-url" method="POST" role="form">
```

Now with the form handler I have the action set to:

```
<form action="/form-handler.php" method="POST" role="form">
```

In my form handler at form-handler.php how can I push the data to https://www.salesforce.com.

PS: Using google captcha and will be auto populating certain form variables to add to complexity.  Below is my form-handler...

```
<?php

    $email;$comment;$captcha;
    if(isset($_POST['email'])){
      $email=$_POST['email'];
    }if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
      $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    }
    if(!$captcha){
      echo '<h2>Please check the the captcha form.</h2>';
      exit;
    }
    $response=file_get_contents("https://www.example.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=-YA-&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    if($response.success==false)
    {
      echo '<h2>Please no spam, thank you.</h2>';
    }else
    {
      header("Location: http://example.com/form-success/");
    }
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

You can curl the data into a remote db.
http://davidwalsh.name/curl-post